# Why is my div element not centering?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I feel like I am missing something easy or stupid. This is the only element on my page that I can't seem to center. I cannot seem to center`ul#footer`.

http://jsfiddle.net/w67rt/

Comment: Looking at your code, dont do this `<li>|</li>` use border on you existing items instead.

Comment: Why not? Please explain.

Comment: You're using mark-up to represent visual effect, this is what CSS is for. To a blind user, using a screen reader, a | when reading out the navigation will mean nothing.

Comment: Does it make me a jerk to not consider my screen-reading brethren? Lol. Didn't even cross my mind. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: No worries mate, spread the accessibility love, thats what I say. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the footer contents horizontally, just add the following CSS:

```
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/GZ6xh/

If you’re looking to center the entire element, just give it a width and then use `margin: 0 auto`:

```
#footer {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This method centers the text inside, not the element itself

Comment: @Tyler Crompton: How is this not standards compliant? It is.

Comment: @Alex: The question wasn’t really clear IMHO. I’ve edited my answer now.

Comment: @Mathias, Woops. I was thinking about something else. My mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The width of ul#footer is undefined, so it uses the default width of "100%". I tried using width:261px, and then it does center.

Comment: Right you are. In order to use margin: auto; as a method of centering a block-level element you'd need to specify a width, otherwise it would take up 100% of the width anyway

Answer (score 0):

I find two solutions:

both here, one is commented:
http://jsfiddle.net/AzNqm/

1. define width of `ul`, and center block with `margin:auto`
2. center inner `li` elements

Effect will be the same.

Comment: @Tyler: I think you’re confusing the CSS `text-align` property with the deprecated `align` attribute in HTML. There’s nothing wrong with `text-align`, no matter how you use it.

Comment: Accidentally deleted the comment trying to edit it. Yes, that's what I thinking about. Little did I know it, though. Lol. Thanks. :)